# List values from objects methods that are in an arraylist of objects?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm learning Java programming and right now I'm exploring the use of objects in arralist. I know how to get a single value out of a object that are in a arraylist like this:

```
customerList.get(0).getAccountOwnerName()
```

EDIT: This how I have done and this is what my question is about. Perhaps there is a better way too do this?

```
for(int i=0;i<customerList.size();i++){
    System.out.println(customerList.get(i).getAccountOwnerName());
    System.out.println(customerList.get(i).getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber());
}
```

THIS IS MY OLD QUESTION:  But know I have a problem and I have searched for a solution to iterate through an arraylist and get each value from the objects methods like getAccountOwnerName and getAccountNumber. I thought this code could be a start, but I need some help to develop it further or perhaps there is some better way to do this? Thanks!

```
System.out.print("List of customer");
Iterator<String> itr = customerList.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String element = itr.next();
    System.out.println(element + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All objects that implement `Collection` like `ArrayList` support the new `for` loop as of Java 1.5.  Really anything that implements [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) does.  This means you can do something like:

```
for (Customer customer : customerList) {
   System.out.println(customer.getAccountOwnerName());
   System.out.println(customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber());
}
```

This should be more efficient that doing repeated `get(i)`.  This uses the iterator method internally but is a lot easier to code to.  Here's a good link of information:

> http://blog.dreasgrech.com/2010/03/javas-iterators-and-iterables.html

You can also iterate through arrays although they don't implement `Iterable`:

```
Customer[] customers = new Customer[100];
customers[0] = new Customer();
...
for (Customer customer : customers) {
   System.out.println(customer.getAccountOwnerName());
   System.out.println(customer.getAccountOwnerPersonalNumber());
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I get a error message like icompatible types when I run this code?! I guess this code list all contents that are inside the objects, but what if I only whant some values?

Comment: I'm aware that String is an object, but perhaps you have miss understood my question? Can really your code get each value from all objects that are inside an array like getting a single value like this: customerList.get().getAccountOwnerName() ??

Comment: I have edit my question. Perhaps I come up with an own solution that works.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  What was missing from your question is that `customerList` is a list of `Customer` objects.  Your iterator implied it was Strings.

Comment: Yes it's a list of Customer objects. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String s : customerList) {
    System.out.println(element + " ");
}
```

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3343771/Using-Foreach-Loops-in-J2SE-15.htm